# Using jQuery to add class to first TD on each table row

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, html-table

I have a table I'm working with that is like such:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tablecontent">
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td>This is the td I want to add a class to.</td>
    <td class="cell2">Stuff</td>
    <td class="cell3">Stuff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tablerow">
    <td>This is the td I want to add a class to.</td>
    <td class="cell2">Stuff</td>
    <td class="cell3">Stuff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first TD tag in each row does not have a class or ID to work with. I don't have access to change the HTML output so I figured to add in a bit of jQuery to target the first TD tag of each tablerow. How would I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#tablecontent td:first-child').addClass('someClass');
```

This uses [the first-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) to select all `<td>` elements in the `#tablecontent` table that are a `first-child` of their parent.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/duKKC/

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below jQuery

```
$('.tablerow').each(function(index) {
    $(this).children('td').first().addClass('class');
});
```

This will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tablerow").find("td:first-child").addClass('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following would work:

```
$('.tablerow td:first-child').addClass('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tablecontent td:first-child').addClass("first-row");
```